# Cannot change the published state when the parent item is of a lesser state

Tags: public, joomla3.0

In Joomla 3.1, I tried to change the published state of an item, but had an error:

> Cannot change the published state when the parent item is of a lesser state.

But my item doesn't have a parent, so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your column for state (published, unpublished, trashed...) is "published".

See https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/table/table.php#L1538